# Wrong screen width on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, media-queries, screen

When I resize the screen of the browser on Google Chrome (I haven't tried on another browser) the value shown is wrong. It makes my work harder when I have to use a media query. I can't find any answers about it. Even if the issue is restricted to Chrome, I would like to know why this happens.

[image: Image - This width]

Doesn't match with

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1067px) {
    //do something
}
```

for example.

EDIT: When I resize the screen to see if my layout broke at a certain width and pick the width shown to use in my media query the query doesnt run at that browser width, but if i put something like 200px more it works but i lose precision.

Using the previous example:

Suppose that is not google site, is my site, and on this width (1067px)I need to center a div.

If I try:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1067px) {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It wont work at the specified value (1067px), but if I put something like max-width: 1267px will work but losing precision.

I dont know exactly how much in px is the variation but is around 200px.

The example of center a div is **only** an example, the fact is: Nothing specified on the query at 1067px work, if I decrease further will work, but too late, forcing me to increase the 1067px to 1267px to run when I want.

**IMPORTANT: I have not tried other browsers besides Chrome.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How much is it out?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1067px) {
    //do something
}
```

I didn't understand your problem well I guess, but I will explain how @media works.

If your screen has from 0 to 1067 width it will work with the css inside this @media screen. It doesn't mean it will limit your screen to some value, you must setup your page to work with max-width of 1067px.

Like this(using max-width on div's and other elements):

```
<div id="home>
//content
</div>
```

And your css would be like this:

```
#home
{
   max-width: 1067px;
}
```

Hope that Helps!